# Scaling of Continuous variables in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, scaling, data-science, logistic-regression

I am performing logistic regression and had a doubt
I have categorical (0,1)as well as continuous variables in my data set..
Now do I need to scale my continuous variables between 0 and 1?
Coz few of my continuous variables have values up to 10k 
Does it make sense to keep such continous values along with categorical variables while performing the logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it is not neccesary. But your resulting system will probably have very small coefficients for the inputs with large range. This can be a problem if you want to use numbers with reduced accuracy (for example 16 bit) for your model.

I am not sure why you are asking if you should use the continuous values in your model. If there is any possibility that they are correlated with the result, keep them. Only if you are sure they are uncorrelated, ignore them.

Comment: Hi,  the thing is in my data set is mixture of continous variables like ( age, balance amount, no of days passed  and the range of balance amount is 2k and days passed is around 1k and that of age is 90) and many categorical variables.. if I don't scale continous variables. Won't my model bias towards the comtinous features having more value? So do I need to scale all the continous variables in range of 0-1 ( m doing logistic regression classification)

Comment: @ChaitanyaPatil: Logistic regression can handle arbitrary input ranges. Only the output is restricted to numbers between 0 and 1. Scaling only makes sense for numerical reasons to avoid the coefficients from getting too small or too large. (I modified the terminology of my answer a bit because I first thought you are using a neural network. But essentially there is no big difference between logistic regression and a single layer backprop network.)

Comment: Thanks! That Helped

Answer (score 1):

For simple linear/logistic regression (without regularization): no need to scale variables.
For linear/logistic regression with regularization: you need to perform scaling.

For linear/logistic regression without regularization you need to scale features only if you'd like to interpret/compare weights after fitting. Otherwise features with higher values will possibly have smaller weights than other ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale by variance and by location. There are many options. My advice is to consider scaling if your variables vary a lot between and within. You can try the following;

All the stuff below here represents a vector, so by X, I mean

[image: eqn1]
. Thus, all I write below are either vectors or matrices.

Scaling by range,

[image: eqn2]
, where R is the range of the variables, basically max(X)-min(X).

Scaling by location (centering), and variance (scaling),

[image: eqn3], where xbar and s are the sample mean and sample variance of X, respectively.

[image: eqn4]

The latter one provides centering as well, so make sure that you select the proper formula for your data. There is no rule of thumb here, but intuiton and inference is a key point. You can also try different combinations of scale and location measures.